# Minimize number of absolute relocations

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, elf, dynamic-linking

There is a Android-targeted dynamic library written in C++. Final binary contains a lot of absolute relocations to the same symbols, E.g. for `__cxa_pure_virtual`. `readelf --relocs` tells next:

```
...
00332fe4  00030502 R_ARM_ABS32            00000000   __cxa_pure_virtual
00332fe8  00030502 R_ARM_ABS32            00000000   __cxa_pure_virtual
00332fec  00030502 R_ARM_ABS32            00000000   __cxa_pure_virtual
00332ff0  00030502 R_ARM_ABS32            00000000   __cxa_pure_virtual
00332ff4  00030502 R_ARM_ABS32            00000000   __cxa_pure_virtual
00332ff8  00030502 R_ARM_ABS32            00000000   __cxa_pure_virtual
00332ffc  00030502 R_ARM_ABS32            00000000   __cxa_pure_virtual
003330f4  00030502 R_ARM_ABS32            00000000   __cxa_pure_virtual
003330f8  00030502 R_ARM_ABS32            00000000   __cxa_pure_virtual
003330fc  00030502 R_ARM_ABS32            00000000   __cxa_pure_virtual
...
```

It has a really huge amount of them. As result during loading dynamic linker will look for the same symbol over and over wasting user's time. As far as I see bionic linker has no way to cache lookup results. And because of this the only way to avoid these insane lookups is to merge somehow all relocations into one.

So does GCC/Clang have any option to control code generation for such scenario? Maybe some option that force generating of another relocation type, that later may be merged by linker with similar ones from other object modules?

Comment: it is a wrapper for unfilled virtuals so you cant.